# Find display who is currently holding Chrome window or tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to capture the position of several tabs in order to know in which display they are currently positioned.

I can get the list of displays with `chrome.system.display.getInfo` and I can get the list of tabs with `chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow` combined with `chrome.windows.getAll`, but I can't seem to find any way to associate a given tab or window with the display that is currently displaying it.

What's the proper way to do it?